# How to divide an SHP entity?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

- I want to divide a unique entity of SHP to multiple entities
- The picture bellow shows a selected entity with area = 993ha
- My objective is to divide this entity to multiple entities where each area is equal to 2ha

[image: The picture bellow shows a selected entity with area = 993ha]

I am using QGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a method to divide your shapefile to exactly what you specify (although I do not know how) but an alternative which should yield you with most areas divided by 2 ha is to:

1. Create a grid using **Vector grid** (*Vector* > *Research Tools* > *Vector grid*) and set the relevant options:

[image: Vector grid]

2. **Clip** your shapefile to your grid layer.
3. Use **Join by location** and select the *Keep all records* option to obtain the same attributes as to where each feature was originally located.

Hope this helps!

Comment: x;y=141.4211356m

Comment: @TamasKosa - Many thanks buddy, corrected the goofy mistake!